# Согласование подлежащего со сказуемым

Tags: грамотная-речь

Читаю в газете:

> Здесь создано пять лабораторий с
> современным оборудованием и две
> мастерские.

*Создано пять* - понятно, но *создано две мастерские* - как-то не так, не лучше ли использовать глагол во мн. числе: *Здесь созданы 5 лабораторий и две мастерские.* Так как правильно? Может, возможны два варианта (здесь вроде бы ед. число подходит для "пять", а мн. число - для "два"). И как правильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласна с Вами, корректно:

Здесь созданы пять лабораторий с современным оборудованием и две мастерские.

Возможен такой вариант:

Здесь создано пять лабораторий с современным оборудованием, а также открыты  две мастерские.

Comment: Спасибо,развеяли мои сомнения.